# How to get the latest version information using APS

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that i want to get the latest version of my app information using Apple Push Notifications.So please tell me how to do this one.I seen in some posts,in that they mension like configure the APNS in apple site and send abinary information to apple service provider.Is it sufficient to get the latest version information.

Comment: You need to be clearer with what you mean about "latest app information"

Comment: If i upload a new version then i nned to get thata information.

Comment: Upload a new version of what? Your app?

Comment: If i add next version of my application to appstore.Then i need to get notification like as new version is available

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own server, to store the identifiers for your users. With this, you can then send notifications to users who have allowed notifications from your app.

Doing this can be quite complicated, so you may want to use a service such as [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com) who will provide the server, and instructions on how to implement APNS in your app.
With this done, it can be quite simple to send a push notification to your users from their website.